# Does a tubular sodium reabsorption cause a stimulation of β2-adrenergic receptors?

Tags: human-biology, physiology

I read the study "The Role of Aldosterone in Obesity-Related Hypertension" and there is one thing I didn't understand. They write: "According to norepinephrine-induced tubular sodium reabsorption, stimulation of β2-adrenergic receptors leads to activation of the Na–Cl cotransporter through suppression of the serine-threonine protein kinase WNK4 in the distal tubule." Is According to meant like due to? So does a tubular sodium Reabsorption cause a Stimulation of β2-adrenergic receptors?

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4886496/

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards. "norepinephrine-induced tubular sodium reabsorption" is the whole process. The β2-adrenergic receptors respond to norepinephrine (this is the "norepinephrine-induced" bit). The receptors then suppress WNK4 in the distal tube ("tubular"), which causes the Na-Cl cotransporter to activate, which in turn causes sodium reabsorption.

This was probably a poorly phrased sentence on the part of the writers, but the sentence follows the same logic as "According to the First Law of Thermodynamics, energy cannot be created or destroyed". The description of the process is just complicated by multiple clauses.